# Trying to fetch a raw file from bitbucket private repository using access token

Tags: automation, version-control, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-api

Im trying to fetch a raw VERSION file from a repository for a CD solution.

I created a `Repository Access Token` with `Repository: Read` permission, as documented [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/repository-access-tokens/)

Using cURL,

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tests/sourcerepo/src/master/VERSION \
∙ -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
∙ -H "Accept: application/json"
```

```
{"type":"error","error":{"message":"You may not have access to this repository or it no longer exists in this workspace. If you think this repository exists and you have access, make sure you are authenticated."}}
```

Using the same URL in Postman with Authorization set to Bearer with the access token, i get

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "error": {
        "message": "Token is invalid or not supported for this endpoint."
    }
}
```

I cant use username and password for this.

Comment: Is the endpoint correct?

Comment: @MB the same endpoint works with username App password authentication.

Comment: Why not use the app password then?